# how could i speed up texture rendering on my pygame raycaster?

Tags: python, optimization, pygame, raycasting

the raycaster I built worked fine by itself, but it got problematic when I added textures. I only get ~1-2fps running the caster with textures on, while >120fps otherwise. I'm pretty new to programming. so I would like some help with optimizations.

"list" is all of the distance values gotten from the raycast. "clist" is the mod of the x & y position where the ray touched the wall. look is the up/down angle the player is looking at.

I removed shading and shadows as it slowed it down even more

```py
def disp(list , clist):
    rayspace = ceil(WIDTH / len(list))
    for i in range(len(list)):   
        top = round(HEIGHT / 2 + 12000/list[i] + (look))
        bottom = round(HEIGHT / 2 - 12000/list[i] + (look))
        if top > bottom:
            tallness = top - bottom
        else:
            tallness = bottom - top
        y = 0
        j = bottom
        while not(j == top):
            y += HEIGHT/tallness
            k = 0
            while not(k == rayspace):
                color = wallpaper.get_at((floor(clist[i]/rayspace + k * 2), floor(y)))
                color = (color[0] , color[1]  ,color[2] )    
                screen.set_at((round(i * rayspace) + k , j) , color)
                k+=1
            j+=1
```

I've replaced my for loops with while loops, removed all global variables, and used "from" on imports, and that helped a bit, but it still is extremely slow

if there is anything that needs clarification about the code I'll be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing, if the result of a calculation is going to be the same for every iteration of a loop, then you don't have to do it every iteration of the loop, you only have to do it once, before the loop. Try something like:

```py
def disp(list , clist):
    rayspace = ceil(WIDTH / len(list))
    half_height = HEIGHT / 2
    for i in range(len(list)):   
        top = round(half_height + 12000/list[i] + (look))
        bottom = round(half_height - 12000/list[i] + (look))
        if top > bottom:
            tallness = top - bottom
        else:
            tallness = bottom - top
        y = 0
        j = bottom
        delta_y = HEIGHT / tallness
        clist_i_div_rayspace = clist[i] / rayspace
        round_i_mul_rayspace = round(i * rayspace)
        while not(j == top):
            y += delta_y
            k = 0
            floor_y = floor(y)
            while not(k == rayspace):
                color = wallpaper.get_at((floor(clist_i_div_rayspace + k * 2), floor_y))
                color = (color[0] , color[1]  ,color[2] )
                screen.set_at((round_i_mul_rayspace + k , j) , color)
                k+=1
            j+=1
```

Also is `not(j == top)` suppose to be faster than `j != top`?

Comment: Thank you I’ll try that,  Im not sure why I did not(j == top) to be honest

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach, instead of rendering each pixel, I used pillow to divide the images into 1 wide slits and then converted them into pygame images using .fromstring(). then resized them to the required tallness. works like a charm now.i imagine there is a faster method, but this works well enough for me